# ListView Not Updating After Calling NotifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

This is My Activity(pActivity5)-

```
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker=new BackgroundWorker(pActivity5.this,this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type,str1);

    arrayList1.clear();
    arrayList2.clear();

    sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("p_name_tech_1",MODE_PRIVATE);

    int a=sharedPreferences.getInt("s_o_a",0);

    for(int i=0;i<a;i++){
        arrayList1.add(i,sharedPreferences.getString(""+i,"null"));
    }
    for(int i=a;i<(a*2);i++){
        arrayList2.add((i-a),sharedPreferences.getString(""+i,"null"));
    }

    adapter=new Adapter(this,arrayList1,arrayList2);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    lv1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This is my onPostExecute method in BackgroundWorker Class-

```
        intent = new Intent(context, pActivity5.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        context.startActivity(intent);
```

When I use backgroundWorker.execute(type,str1).get(); then it works fine but that Defeats the purpose of AsyncTask.
So I want to use AsyncTask and update my ListView on its completion.

I have even tried this-
[How to get the result of OnPostExecute() to main activity because AsyncTask is a separate class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)
but no success.

Comment: Why not using `lv1.setAdapter(adapter);` in `onPostExecute` ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK because both are in different Class

Comment: @AvinashSaran What is wrong the solution in the SO thread that you have mentioned in your post?

Comment: @AvinashSaran: pass lv1 to backgroundWorker class

Comment: @AvinashSaran create a callback inside onPostExecute to your pActivity5 and then update your listview

Comment: @sohanshetty It's giving null pointer exception

Comment: @sohanshetty I wrote this in onPostExecute() after context.startActivity(intent);
---
            ArrayList<String> arrayList=new ArrayList<String>();
            ArrayList<String> arrayList1=new ArrayList<String>();
            arrayList.add(0,"avinash");
            arrayList1.add(0,"saran");
            pActivity5 pActivity5=new pActivity5();
            pActivity5.adapter=new Adapter(context,arrayList,arrayList1);
            pActivity5.lv1.setAdapter(pActivity5.adapter);

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I am getting null pointer exception

Comment: @AvinashSaran you shouldn't do it like above approach it is wrong and you cannot create object for activity class

Comment: @sohanshetty then what should I do?

Comment: post your Backgroundworker class i will tell you